# Finding input elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the difference in days between two input fields that contain dates. I am pretty much unable to alter the HTML so I have to do this with Javascript. The HTML is pretty ugly. I can only use jQuery 1.3.2.

HTML:

```
<div id="longUnreadableUnidentifiableId">
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="column">
        <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtFrom" type="text">11/02/2002</input>
      </span>
      <span class="colum">
        <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtUntil" type="text">16/12/2010</input>
      </span>
      <div class="diff"> [diff] </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="longUnreadableUnidentifiableId2">
  <div class="dynamic">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="column">
        <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtFrom" type="text">03/03/2003</input>
      </span>
      <span class="colum">
        <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtUntil" type="text">16/12/2010</input>
      </span>
      <div class="diff"> [diff] </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When any one of the dates on a certain line change, the difference between them should show. I'm using moment.js for the date diff.

The following javascript tries to find the associated input field and alert the difference between them. However, I am having trouble finding the second input field (var until).

Javascript:

```
$('input[id*="txtFrom"]').live('change', function() { 
    var from = $(this);
    var until = from.parent(".row").find('input[id*="txtUntil"]');

    a = moment(from.val());
    b = moment(until.val());

    alert(b.diff(a, 'days'));
});
```

Does someone have a solution to this problem? Perhaps something more elegant?

Comment: You biggest issue seems to be: <<I can only use jQuery 1.3.2>>

Comment: Could you expand on why you are constrained to using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: The site on which I'm making this change is pretty significant and I cannot upgrade jQuery in case of breaking changes. I do not have the time or resources to properly test it. The decision is not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `parents` instead of `parent`. `parent` just checks the immediate parent, whereas `parents` checks all of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Some suggestions:**

1. Correct your html syntax, use

   ```
   <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtFrom" type="text" value="11/02/2002"></input>
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <input id="horribleHorribleLongIdTxtFrom" type="text">11/02/2002</input>
   ```
2. your element id `horribleHorribleLongIdTxtFrom` coming twice in
   same page, you are breaking the html rule.

Comment: (1) Are you sure? It works here... (2, 3) I have no way to edit the HTML, and yes, it is indeed breaking the HTML rule. Old code :(

Comment: @kabforks: pardon bro, it's my mistake about (1). That's y I removed

Comment: <input ...> tags don't need closing </input> tags, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue