# Return checked option from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am using radio boxes to save values into an array, the issue I am having is trying to automatically check the checkbox for the corresponding value after the page is refresh or whatever

I have tried the following;

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Floating</h3></br>
<input type="radio" name="lu_ban_data[noticeType]" value="multi"<?php echo ('multi' == get_option( 'noticeType' ))? 'checked="checked"':''; ?> /></input>

<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Floating</h3></br>
<input type="radio" name="lu_ban_data[noticeType]" value="floating"<?php echo ('floating' == get_option( 'noticeType' ))? 'checked="checked"':''; ?> /></input>
```

The value is being saved when I click either one `array (size=6)
  'noticeType' => string 'multi' (length=5)` but the corresponding checkbox isnt being checked.

[image: value]

Anyone help?

[image: checkbox]

**output markup**

```
<div style="margin: 10px;">
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Multiple</h3></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="lu_ban_data[noticeType]" value="multi" /></input>
                        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Floating</h3></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="lu_ban_data[noticeType]" value="floating" /></input>
                    </div>
```

the "checked" is not being printed

Comment: What is the value of `get_option('noticeType')`?

Comment: multi or floating depends on which of the two checkboxes i click then it gets saved into an array but when the page is refresh, the radio isnt checked

Comment: Can you double check? Otherwise, check if `checked="checked"` gets printed.

Comment: If you could give us  final markup that would be helpful. Also, do note that inputs are a void tag, and do not need a closing ``</input>`` [info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/1048479)

Comment: here is the value http://i.stack.imgur.com/Oadja.png but the checked is not being printed

Comment: usually to echo back the value stored in the key "noticeType" I use `<?php $value= get_option('lu_ban_data'); echo $value['noticeType']; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work like so;

```
value="multi" <?php $value = get_option('lu_ban_data'); checked( $value['noticeType'], 'multi' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say its in an array? how are you getting that array?

To use get_option() at some point you have to use update_option()

Try echo get_option( 'noticeType' ) and see what is stored in the wordpress option.

Comment: I added that in the question, currently is `floating`