# Change textbox value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I usually don't program in jQuery so I'm a big newbie. I got an HTML `input` form (type=text) and I want that when website is loaded, the value of the textbox should change.

I got this in `fill-in.php` file:

```
<script src="fill.js"></script>
<body>
<label class="txtlabel">Username/Email</label>
<input id="username" value="Moin" type="text" name="login-username">
<label class="txtlabel">Kennwort</label>
<input id="kennwort" value="Passwort" type="password" name="login-password">
</body>
```

And in `fill.js` file I wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#username').val('some random text')
});
```

`fill.js` is correctly linked to my `fill-in.php` file.

Can someone give me a hint where I made a mistake?

Cheers

Comment: whether jQuery library is included.... check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: f12 is your friend, what is the error in the console if there is one?

Comment: Close these input tags!

Comment: @MelanciaUK what for?

Comment: It's working just fine, even with the wrong markup and the missing semicolon. http://jsfiddle.net/jTX7X/

Comment: @AdamWolski the right question is: Why not? It doesn't cause any harm to keep the markup well formed.

Comment: There is an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". What about this? Have I to write `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: You didn't add the jQuery library.

Comment: you need to include the jquery library before the fill.js

Comment: @MelanciaUK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue

Comment: @AdamWolski when I said close them, I meant like this: `<input name="foo" type="text" />`

Comment: @MelanciaUK + html5 spec http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-input-element

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes, this is valid in XHTML, but it is not necessary with html5

Comment: @AdamWolski Not every single browser/browser version renders HTML5. So, I still prefer to keep them closed. It's just an extra character anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to use jQuery, the very first thing you need is the library. You can reference it from a CDN or download it:

http://jquery.com/download/

```
<!-- CDN reference (Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fill.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah nice. Didn't know this because I usually not programming in jQuery. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries dude. It happens.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your header section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the jquery library before the fill.js, you can download it from the [jQuery site](http://jquery.com/download/) or use a CDN version as given below

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="fill.js"></script>
```