# Form Closing Tag Not Showing In Console

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

its very strange that i am closing the form input field tags but even though i didn’t find it in console.even my form value didn't getting posted.
here is my code

```
<form ng-submit="updatepersonel()" ng-repeat="update in userDetail">
               <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.firstname" ng-value="update.firstname" />
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">First Name</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="perupdate.lastname" ng-value="update.lastname" />
              </div>
               <div class="form-group" />
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.firstname" ng-value="update.phone" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Location</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.location" ng-value="update.location" />
              </div>
             <button  class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
            </form>
```

Edited::

```
<div class="form-group">
               <form ng-submit="updatepersonel()" ng-repeat="update in userDetail">


                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.firstname" ng-value="update.firstname" />
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">First Name</label>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="perupdate.lastname" ng-value="update.lastname" />
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.firstname" ng-value="update.phone" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Location</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control full" ng-model="perupdate.location" ng-value="update.location" />
              </div>
             <button  class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>

            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: That self-closing div may be messing it up `div class="form-group" />`, which then gives you a stray `</div>`. Console shows not only just the HTML as it was rendered, but also the result of the browser trying to fix incorrect HTML.

Comment: Form Still not posting same issue with input tag, see my updated code.

Comment: Also i am not getting data in ng-value in input field

Comment: Don't do `<inuput />` ... instead do `<input>` ... it [doesn't need to be closed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/398606).

Comment: I tried that too, but even i am not getting data in my text boxes

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my issue.

what i was doing i was trying to get the data in `ng-value`.
But when i try to bind data in my `ng-model` i get the solution

js

```
$scope.perupdate= {
                  firstname: key.firstname,
                  lastname : key.lastname,
                  phone    : key.phone,
                  location : key.location, 
              };
```

view

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control full"  ng-model="perupdate.firstname">
```