# Changing value of input based on another input box and multiplied currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the value of an input box to be that of another input boxes' value times the price of an item. I have the currency wrapped in a span tag with a class. I need to multiply that value times the `.productTextInput` input text box. That value will show in the `.subTotal` box. How do I accomplish this?

jQuery:

```
$(".productTextInput").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var priceAmount = $(this).parents().find(".priceAmount").text();

        $(this).parents().find(".subTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * parseInt(priceAmount, 10));
    });
});
```

html:

```
<table class="productTable productSmall" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 27%;">
               <strong>American (wild) plum</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="custom-tag"></td>
            <td class="custom-tag">
                Prunus americana
            </td>
            <td class="custom-tag">
                Bare Root
            </td>
            <td class="custom-tag" style="border-right: 2px solid #000;">
                2' - 3' size
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;padding-right: 10px;">
                $<span class="priceAmount">1.75</span>
            </td>
            <td class="quantity">
                <input id="Units_4996263" class="productTextInput" name="AddToCart_Amount" value="1" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="subTotal" name="subTotal" readonly="readonly" type="text">
            </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This isnt the full answer to your question, but you aren't closing your input tags. It should be `<input id="id" />` <-- missing space and `/`

Comment: @wahwahwah That doesn't actually affect anything if you don't. Good advice, as it's best to be consistent syntax wise, but the HTML will render without errors if they're missing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue to better understand.

Comment: @wahwahwah This is due to the input being generated by the system via a tag. I didn't include the tag as it wouldn't make sense. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` if you want to a number with decimals.

Also you should remove the `each` function you're calling:

```
$(".productTextInput").each(function() {
   $(this).change(function() {
```

Just use a `click` function and `$(this)` will refer to the clicked element. You can simplify your code to the following:

```
$(".productTextInput").change(function() {

     var priceAmount = parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find(".priceAmount").text());

     $(this).closest("tr").find(".subTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * priceAmount)  

});
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kprhtovh/)

Comment: What if the OP is building a webshop and there are multiple product inputs? `Each` provides each of those inputs with a change handler.

Comment: right and assuming they're in their own table row, this will do just that. An `each` loop is not necessary if you specify your targets right: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kprhtovh/1/)

Comment: I have chosen this answer because it is correct and I like the approach to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat` on `priceAmount`. `parseInt` returns an integer (strips the decimals). parseFloat keeps the decimals.

In your current code `priceAmount` is always `1` due to the parseInt.

Change to:

```
$(this).parents().find(".subTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) * parseFloat(priceAmount));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.each` on this since `$('.productTextInput')` looks for every element with the supplied class.

I did omit parseInt/parseFloat in the snippet but the JSFiddle has it. http://jsfiddle.net/6qf7oc55/3/

```js
$('.productTextInput').blur(function() {
    num = this.value;
    price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.priceAmount').text();
    sub = num * price;
    $('.subTotal').val(sub.toFixed(2));
});
```