# JQuery: select <p> inside an input checkbox type

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input, selector

I want to change my `<p>` tag style.

My html code:

```
<input type="checkbox"><p> paragraph</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.list').on("click", "input", function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(this).find('p').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    } else {
        $(this).find('p').css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paragraphs aren't inside your `input` tags. Try using `next` instead of `find`:

```
$('ul.list').on("click", "input", function(){

    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(this).next('p').css("text-decoration" ,  "line-through");
    } else {
        $(this).next('p').css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: thanks a lot, both of this and ErikLundgren's method are working :D

Answer (score 2):

The `<input>` element is a void element ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/3932826)) and as such is not expected to contain any elements. You can use `.next()` or `.siblings()` instead to get the effect you want.

```js
$('ul.list').on("click", "input", function(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
    $(this).next('p').css("text-decoration" ,  "line-through");
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('p').css("text-decoration", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"><p> paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS only solution for that behaviour:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + p {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's good but i append checkbox by click button function and this doesn't working.
don't worry i had just found the solution. :D thanks!

Comment: @ĐứcHợpTrần that handles any dynamic element so you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** function.

```js
 $('ul.list').on("click", "input:checkbox", function () {
    $(this)
        .next('p')
        .css("text-decoration", this.checked ? "line-through" : "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or you can you use **[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** function

```js
$('ul.list').on("click", "input", function() {
    $(this).siblings('p')
        .css("text-decoration", this.checked ? "line-through" : "none")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but it's not working :D i had find the solution

Comment: @ĐứcHợpTrần  I don't know what is going on there, but this is working perfectly. I added code snipet, check it.