# Can I use self-closing tags with input elements?

Tags: html

`<input>` doesn't have any child elements, so it seems to me like the proper syntax would be `<input/>`. Is this supported in modern browsers?

A quick test in Chrome seems like Chrome converts `<input/>` to `<input>`. Do all browsers do this?

Comment: Realistically, the validity would depend on which doctype you declare.
In this context, /> is valid with HTML 5 and XHTML doctypes and invalid with HTML 4.01 doctypes, this is what I have read somewhere I believe

Comment: Highly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan The doctype does not matter. No HTML specification has ever called for a closing slash on the `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

[The HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-input-element) states and clearly shows by example that the proper syntax is `<input>`. While `<input/>` is allowed, and called a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), the closing slash has no meaning, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

If you are concerned about how a browser will handle it, the best advice, as always, is to do what the specification says to do and always use the specified and always valid `<input>`.

Comment: This answer is correct as long the doctype is declared as HTML5.

Comment: @OrlandoMorales-Cochran My answer is correct no matter the doctype. No HTML specification has ever used a closing slash for `<input>`.

Comment: Yes it is correct no matter the specification. I do believe older specs did't ignore the slash as they do in HTML5. That was his question. Do all browsers ignore the slash? There was never any standard on how browsers treated it so it could have been interpreted differently depending on the browser. With HTML5, browsers completely ignore it.

Comment: Wouldn't XHTML have required it?

Comment: @Shadow XHTML is XML. XHTML is a different specification.

Comment: @Rob Perhaps, but it is a valid HTML specification. You're right on other counts though.

Comment: @Shadow XHTML is **not** a valid HTML specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/ XHTML is HTML reformulated as XML.

Answer (score 1):

The WHATWG spec requires that modern browsers support void elements, though the main editor of the spec is notably opposed to calling a document XML (and including self-closing elements) if it isn't served with a XML mime type.

Chrome and Firefox rewrite that void tag by removing the slash, but Microsoft Edge doesn't.

The spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/ is old, from 2010. The official Living HTML spec includes what the WHATWG calls "[the XML syntax](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#the-xhtml-syntax)" of HTML5, so it's not correct to say that developers may not use it, as long as the document is served as `application/xhtml+xml` (though that's rare) and it has an XML namespace such as `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">`.

For example, according to [Validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu/), this document, even though it includes a void `<input/>` element, is valid "HTML5 + ARIA + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0":

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p><input/></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

For me, this is not mere theory or nitpicking. I had to use XML syntax at my last job or my work couldn't get done. When I didn't include closing slashes on void elements in my web templates, our expensive enterprise-level content management system would arbitrarily rearrange or remove divs. So it was difficult to get our CMS to produce HTML *without* XML syntax. That convinced me that insisting on removing closing slashes can be as cult-like as insisting on including them.

More discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/1584531

Comment: The question is regarding HTML. You are speaking of XML and XHTML which are unrelated to this question and an entirely different specification. The HTML specification is quite clear and gives examples showing the closing slash is not needed, means nothing, and is ignored.

Comment: As I typed that I realized that yours is a commentary and not an answer to the question. Please do not put comments in the Answer section.

Comment: I've edited my answer to deal more specifically with the OP's questions, which are: 1) Is `<input/>` supported in modern browsers? and 2) Do all browsers convert `<input/>` to `<input>`?

Answer (score 0):

No, `<input/>` (and `<br/>`, `<hr/>`, `<image/>`, and so on) is **not** proper syntax for HTML (any version). It's just that the HTML5 spec describes how these XML-isms are ignored/recovered by lenient parsers. There's also the cargo-cult usage of `<input />` (eg. with a space between the element name and the slash character in the hope a browser would ignore it more robustly than without).

These practices came up with XHTML and the desire to use XML tools for HTML, or to author content for HTML and XHTML simultaneously, but are generally discouraged in modern HTML.

Comment: FYI: I can't find a reference for it, but old timers say that putting a space before the slash character was necessary to keep Netscape 4 (ca 1997) from interpreting the  tag as `<input/>` instead of `<input>`. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/17200/63591