# Send data to another page using jQuery based on the which button was pressed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var btn = $('a.btn-primary'); 
var closeDate = $('td.closeDate');
var applyBtn = $('<input type="button" value=" Apply " class="toggleButton" \>');

//Rmove a link
btn.remove();

//Add button
applyBtn.insertAfter(closeDate);

$('.toggleButton').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = {
            vacancyID: obj.find('td.vacancyID').text(),
            closeDate: obj.find('td.closeDate').text(),
            roleLongTitle: obj.find('td.roleLongTitle').text(),
            roleRequirements: obj.find('td.roleRequirements').text(),
            roleResponsibilities: obj.find('td.roleResponsibilities').text(),
            roleQualifications: obj.find('td.roleQualifications').text(),
        }

         //Post the data to the page
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'vacancy.php',
             data: data,
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
        //$.post("vacancy.php", data, function(){
            //alert(data);
        //});
        console.log(data.vacancyID);
    })
});
```

In the console the data display correct, but alert shows something completely.  The page I am posting all also don't see the post.  See image below:
[image]

I was expecting to only see the data that relates to the button I clicked and not both vacancies.  Can anyone please help and tell we where I am going wrong.

Comment: Your console and alert contains two different values. `console.log(data.vacancyID);` and `alert(data);` Alert will print everything inside `data` while console just prints `vacancyID`

Comment: you need to do `alert(data.vacancyID);`

Comment: Sorry, the console log must read `console.log(data)`.  The console log shows the data based on which button is clicked.

Comment: @Willem what is the console result.

Comment: you need to use a different variable for `data: data,` since `success: function(data){` is the callback for `url: 'vacancy.php',` you might end up confusing things here. so it's best to be safe.

Comment: @5740382 the the vacancyID and the rest of the data in that line that relates to it from the button I clicked.  I don't know how to add a screen shot (image) into a reply sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 points:

1. We don't have `\` in the end of input tag. Please remove it.

   `var applyBtn = $('<input type="button" value=" Apply " class="toggleButton" \>');`
2. Apply button should be appended into `td` tag, not inserting after `td`, because `tr` contains `td`or `th`, `input` is not a kind of table element.

   `applyBtn.insertAfter(closeDate);`

Somehow, incorrect node will effect to our functionalities.

3. Your `data` was alerted is not your `data` variables. It's response data.

`success: function(data){
   alert(data);
}`

is should be:

`success: function(res){
   alert(data);
}`

Comment: but we have `/` to close an input tag. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue)

Comment: @hungrykoala I had updated the answer, check last point.
`input` have no `/` or `/` anyway. Just want to correct :)

Comment: `<td class="closeDate">
       <?php
      //Convert the mySQL date to PHP date
        echo convertToDate($closeDate);
        ?>
 </td>
 <td>
                                    <a href="apply.php?vacID=<?php echo $vacancyID; ?>&vacDesc=<?php echo $shortTitle; if($UID !== NULL){ ?>&UID=<?php echo $UID; } if($staffID !==                                       NULL){ ?>&stmem=<?php echo $staffID; } ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Apply</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>` This is where my button gets inserted.