# HTML Input sometimes end with /> and sometimes end with >

Tags: html, input

I noticed that some inputs end with a closing tag /> and with >. Is there a reason why? When I test the code with /> and > tag I don't see any differences. Is it maybe that some people are forgetting to add the closing tag? It makes sense to me to use a /> closing tag at the end of every input.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/7919626

Comment: Read this - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-elements.php

Answer (score 0):

the convention is or was if there is an opening and closing tag you don't use the / example is

```
<body>
</body>
```

if the tag is self-closing it is included by convintion.

```
<br/>
```

however, this changes based on the doctype declared and input is a bit of an exception:

in HTML 5 input with the slash is fine either way but in HTML 4.01 it is invalid to add the slash.

hope that helped!