# I have a notepad that for each note - has a title and the main content. How do I make the content appear/disappear when clicking the title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has notes within it (each note has a title and content). When creating a new note, it gets its own title and content added into this div.

```
<div class="notes-list">
  <h4 class="note-title">Title</h4>
  <input class="note-content">Note content</input>
</div>
```

How can I make the input hide/show when I click on the title related to it?

```
const titles = document.querySelectorAll(".note-title");
const noteContent = document.querySelectorAll(".note-content");

titles.forEach(function(title) {
  title.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // unsure how to select the corresponding input related to the title:
    noteContent.style.display = "inline-block";
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried a jQuery `.toggle()` method? It toggles between `.hide()` & `.show()`

Comment: I'm trying to do this without using jQuery (we are building a note app with only html, css and vanilla js)

Comment: I think toggle is not jQuery only. It should work also in pure JS. Check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Comment: Have you tried `noteContent.style.display = noteContent.style.display === "inline-block" ? "none" : "inline-block";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not that far off. Just a few changes necessary. Since `querySelectorAll` returns a nodeList you cannot access your element directly, instead we can use the `index` from our `forEach` to find the correct element.

The easiest method to toggle elements would be to use a CSS class together with `classList.toggle()`. Another option could be to check its `display` style and change the property accordingly.

As a side note: An `input` element is selfclosing meaning the `</input>` is obsolete. If you want to give it a label use as the name suggests the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element. More info on closing an input tag in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/3257622).

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll(".note-title");
const noteContent = document.querySelectorAll(".note-content");

titles.forEach(function(title, index) {
  title.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // unsure how to select the corresponding input related to the title:
    noteContent[index].classList.toggle("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="notes-list">
  <h4 class="note-title">Title 1</h4>
  <label>
    <input class="note-content">
    Note content 1
  </label>
  
  <h4 class="note-title">Title 2</h4>
  <label>
    <input class="note-content">
    Note content 2
  </label>
  
  <h4 class="note-title">Title 3</h4>
  <label>
    <input class="note-content">
    Note content 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly how I wanted it to!