# Last label refuses to show - the one where it asks about recommendation

Tags: html, css

Here is all the code so far. Everything else shows up just fine

```html
<h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
<p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us imrpove our platform</p>
<form id="survey-form" action: "https://survey-form.freecodecamp.rocks/">
  <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label></br>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></br>
  <label id="email-label">Email</label></br>
  <input required type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"></br>

  <label id="number-label">Age</label></br>
  <input type="number" id="number" name="age" min="13" max="125" placeholder="Age"></br>
  <label for="role" id="question">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="" placeholder="Select your role">
      <option value="Student">Student</option>
      <option value="Full time job">Full-time job</option>
      <option value="Full time learner">Full-time learner</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </br>

      <div>
        <label for="recommend" name="recommend">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
        <input type="radio" id="definitely" name="answer" value="definitely">Definitely</input>
        <input type="radio" id="notsure" name="answer" value="notsure">Not Sure</input>
        <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="no">No</input>
      </div>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing to display that ONE question

Comment: Do you have any css?

Comment: You have numerous syntax errors that [a testing tool](https://validator.nu/#textarea) would find for you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232121/closing-html-input-tag-issue input shouldn't be closed. + there are a bunch of unclosed tags in your code + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br  </br> is not valid

Answer (score -2):

The `<select>` element should be closed properly with `</select>`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>freeCodeCamp Survey Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF=8" lang="en">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us improve our platform</p>
    <form id="survey-form" action:"https://survey-form.freecodecamp.rocks/">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label></br>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></br>
        <label id="email-label">Email</label></br>
        <input required type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"></br>
        <label id="number-label">Age</label></br>
        <input type="number" id="number" name="age" min="13" max="125" placeholder="Age"></br>
        <label for="role" id="question">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
        <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your role</option>
            <option value="Student">Student</option>
            <option value="Full time job">Full-time job</option>
            <option value="Full time learner">Full-time learner</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></br>

        <div>
            <label for="recommend" name="recommend">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="definitely" name="answer" value="definitely">Definitely</input>
            <input type="radio" id="notsure" name="answer" value="notsure">Not Sure</input>
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="no">No</input>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HeatherFeather did you solved your problem?

Answer (score -3):

You're missing your `select` closing tag so the browser knows that the code below it is not part of the `select` and behave unexpectadly. Just add `</select>` after the last `option` and your label should show up.

Edit: Didn't realize @Dulan Jayawickrama found the problem

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>freeCodeCamp Survey Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF=8" lang="en">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title">freeCodeCamp Survey Form</h1>
  <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us imrpove our platform</p>
  <form id="survey-form" action: "https://survey-form.freecodecamp.rocks/">
    <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label></br>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></br>
    <label id="email-label">Email</label></br>
    <input required type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"></br>

    <label id="number-label">Age</label></br>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="age" min="13" max="125" placeholder="Age"></br>
    <label for="role" id="question">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="" placeholder="Select your role">
        <option value="Student">Student</option>
        <option value="Full time job">Full-time job</option>
        <option value="Full time learner">Full-time learner</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>

    </select>
    </br>

    <div>
      <label for="recommend" name="recommend">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
      <input type="radio" id="definitely" name="answer" value="definitely">Definitely</input>
      <input type="radio" id="notsure" name="answer" value="notsure">Not Sure</input>
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="no">No</input>
    </div>
```